# Constructing a MongoDB query to emulate JavaScript filtering logic (filter+every) using Mongoose for multiple search terms

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**Introduction**

I am building a search feature using mongodb with mongoose ODM. The codebase is already having an search feature using javascript. The code

```
  terms.every((term) => {
    const cleanedTerm = term.trim();

    return (
      usernameLower.includes(cleanedTerm) ||
      nameLower.includes(cleanedTerm) ||
      userTagsString.includes(cleanedTerm) ||
      userLocationString.includes(cleanedTerm)
    );
  });
```

First all the users are fetched and then getting filtered. The documents which consists of every elements of the array in any of its fields are getting returned.

**My Approach**

```
async function searchUsers(termsArray) {
  const query = { $in: termsArray }
  return await Profile.find({
    $or: [
      { username: query },
      { name: query },
      { "location.name": query },
      { tags: { $all: termsArray } },
    ],
  });
}
```

**Problem and Example**
Basically this query is returning the documents which is matching any of the elements of the  terms or tags.
Example - Suppose a profile is having tags [JS,TS,OSS] and search terms are [JS,TS,OSS,JAVA] then also the profile is getting returned which is not expected as JAVA is not present.

Comment: Do you want `$and` instead of `$or`? Presently your `$all` condition can fail but docs will still be returned if they pass a single other branch of the `$or`

Comment: Don't you think adding and will lead to checking of all the fields instead of every terms of the array?

Comment: So do you only want profiles to be returned if ALL tags listed in the `termsArray` are present in the profile, and if ANY of the `termsArray` terms are present in either the `username` `name` `location.name` of the same profile? Because at the minute your aggregation is returning profiles if any of the `$or` conditions are met. For example, that means if there is a match in `username` it doesn't even need to evaluate the rest of the conditions.

Comment: Yes. Can share the code to evaluate this

Answer (score 0):

So if you only want profiles to be returned if ALL tags listed in the `termsArray` are present in the profile, and if ANY of the `termsArray` terms are present in either the `username` or `name` or `location.name` of the same profile then you need to combine `$and` with `$or`. Refactor your aggregation like so:

```
async function searchUsers(termsArray) {
   const query = { $in: termsArray };
   return await Profile.find({
       $and: [
           {
               $or: [
                   { username: query },
                   { name: query },
                   { "location.name": query }
               ]
           },
           { tags: { $all: termsArray } }
       ]
   });
}
```

The `$and` states that both conditions need to be true. One of those conditions is an `$or` so any of the 3 conditions in the `$or` can be true but the `{ tags: { $all: termsArray } }` must also be true.

See this [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Duu9qzC8vvP) for a working example. I have taken your `Profile` properties to be `username`, `name`, `location` as an object with a `name` property and `tags` as an array of values. You will see that the word JAVA is present in the the first 4 documents but only in one area. Only in the 5th document does JAVA appear in a property and the `tags` has an exact match. If you run it you will see only the 5th document is returned. This solves your problem as you described. Let me know if your problem differs.

Answer (score -1):

first thing you have use $or so any of condition satisfied it will return records,
any username or name matches in record and that record is having this [JS,TS,OSS,JAVA] it is valid,
you have to make condition using $AND or otherwise

you can try $ size along with you query

```
async function searchUsers(termsArray) {
const query = { $in: termsArray }
return await Profile.find({
 $or: [
  { username: query },
  { name: query },
  { "location.name": query },
  { tags: { $size: termsArray.length, $all: termsArray } },
 ],
});
}
```

Comment: Not working cause it is as same as my approach.